# htaccess removing extra directory names in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, directory

I have something like:

```
(obvious)domain.com/cityname1/cityname2/citynameN/myscript.html
```

How do I keep `cityname1`, remove `cityname2-N` and keep the `scriptname`?  (In this case `myscript.html`.)

I want:

```
(obvious)domain.com/cityname1/myscript.html
```

Comment: Typically this is done via regex, as you note. What have you tried thus far? What results have you gotten for various sample inputs? Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving my condition more towards the top & have to have 2, but here it is:

#2+ folders - as long as you already haven't addded http://www. to %{HTTP_HOST} :

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(images|img|css|js) [NC] #Exclude any directories you want to actually use

RewriteRule (.*)(/\w+/)(.*/)(.*)$ http:/www.domain.com/$1/$4 [L,NC]

#1 folder - as long as you already haven't addded http://www. to %{HTTP_HOST} :

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(images|img|css|js) [NC] #Exclude any directories you want to actually use

RewriteRule (.*)(/\w+/)(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/$3 [L,NC]